# Random class not defined in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working under ubuntu, and need to create some random number in my app(Not secure randoms just unsafe randoms). I use the Random class that ruby 1.9.2 provides but it seems that is not defined on rails, any idea on how to fix ?

```
$irb 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Random
 => Random
```

```
 rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 3.0.3)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Random
NameError: uninitialized constant Random
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

Here are the details of the box:

```
Linux thomas-laptop 2.6.32-26-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 24 10:14:11 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

thomas@thomas-laptop:~/dev/foo$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3
thomas@thomas-laptop:~/dev/foo$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: It works ok for me (on MacOSX), can you just use `Kernel#rand`?

Comment: This is strange, the only difference in my configuration is that I use `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]` (i.e., OS X instead of Linux), but that should not make a difference. I'll try on Linux.

Comment: I just created a new rails project in Linux, and it works for me there, too: uname `Linux dev 2.6.18-028stab070.7 #1 SMP Fri Oct 1 13:53:00 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS), ruby -v `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]`, rails 3.0.3.

Comment: Works for me on OSX and Ruby 1.9.2p0, rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on both rails 3.0.0 and rails 3.0.3, using ruby 1.9.2-p0 under OS X and Linux.

- ruby -v: `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]` (installed from rvm)
- rails -v: `Rails 3.0.3`
- uname -a: `Linux dev 2.6.18-028stab070.7 #1 SMP Fri Oct 1 13:53:00 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Have you tried on a clean rails project? Are you using any Gems which might interfere?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'backports' gem, available [here](https://github.com/marcandre/backports).